# disproving union of infinitely many regular languages

Tags: computability, automata, regular-language

I want to disprove the following statement:

"if $L$ is the union of infinitely many regular languages, then $L$ is guaranteed to be a regular language."

I don't know where to start. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every finite language is regular.  Pick any language of which you know it isn't regular and write it as the union of infinitely many finite languages.

Comment: Aren't regular languages supposed to be closed under the Union operator?

Comment: Yes, finite unions.

Comment: That is true. Thanks!